# The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked When i insert table in inkwell

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nLrf.jpg)

I'm facing the error and i tried everything but error did'nt remove

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    dbHelper.insert(
          Cart(
            id: index,
            productid: index.toString(),
            productname: productname[index]
                .toString(),
            inititalprice:
                productprice[index],
            productprice:
                productprice[index],
            quantity: 1,
            unittag: productunit[index]
                .toString(),
            image: productimage[index]
                .toString()))
        .then((Value) {
      print("Product is added to Cart");
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
  },
  child: Container(),
)
```